# Change in Frequency while Tearing Paper

Tags: acoustics, frequency, harmonics

Let us assume you have a 30cm strip of paper, and you tear it lengthwise. Let us abbreviate the frequency produced when you reach the end of the paper as $f_2$ and the frequency of sound heard when you start tearing the paper as $f_1$. My question is, would $f_1$ be greater than, lesser than, or equal to $f_2$?

[image]

This was one of the questions asked in an examination I attempted today.

My initial answer to this problem was based on the fact that as one tears a paper lengthwise, while pulling it upwards and ripping it, an air column would form below the paper and if one was to consider the point at which the paper was being torn as a node, and the 30cm mark of the paper as the antinode, the wavelength should conceptually increase as you tear the paper further.
$$v=f\lambda$$
Therefore, if $\lambda$ increases, $f$ must decrease.
And hence, $f_1>f_2$ must hold true.

A few hours after my examination was over, I thought of another way of explaining the same. While tearing a paper, one puts their hand on one side of the paper and rips it lengthwise from the other side. Hence, the paper would be in tension throughout the process. If we were to consider the paper akin to a tensed string, the relation below would hold true.
$$f=\frac{1}{2L}\sqrt{\frac{T}{\mu}}$$
Where $\mu$ indicates linear density.

If this relation was to hold true for a paper, as the paper length decreases, the frequency should increase and hence $f_2>f_1$ would hold true.

Both my explanations for the same problem contradict one-another. I'm sure one out of the two is incorrect but I don't know which one. Which out of these is right and if anyone has a better explanation for this question, I would really appreciate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that the tension in the paper causes the paper to vibrate, which produces the sound. The fibers in the paper snap as the paper rips, releasing energy, some of which is carried by transverse waves in the sheet. But the part of the paper that vibrates most vigorously is the torn edge itself, since it is in direct contact with the snapping fibers. This edge gets longer as you rip the paper, and as you said this implies the frequency decreases as a result.

The size of the air column is not relevant here. This is because, unlike a wind instrument, the sound isn't produced by resonances in a tube. You could rip a piece of paper far away from any table and hear the same sound. Instead, this situation is more like hitting a snare drum, with transverse waves on a 2D sheet. (The snapping fibers are like the drumstick hitting the drumskin, imparting energy to the sheet at the location of the tear.) You can convince yourself this is true by trying to rip wet paper; it produces hardly any sound because the medium has much more inertia (and vibrates much less as a result).

Your second answer is very close to correct, except the relevant wave is actually increasing in length. This is because the paper is getting "plucked" at wherever the end of the tear is, and the tension is provided by your hands, which are at the beginning of the tear.